# Determine all possible automorphisms of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Let $G$ be the undirected graph whose vertex set is $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ and edge set $\{ab, ae, bc, be, cd, ce, de\}$.  The graph is drawn below:

[image: Drawing of the graph G]

Let $V$ denote the set of vertices of the graph G defined. Determine all possible isomorphisms $\varphi:V\:\:\xrightarrow{}\:V$ from the graph $G$ to itself that satisfy $\varphi(b)=c.$

---

Ok, so I know what a graph isomorphism is and how to check if a graph is isomorphic what is puzzling me is how to determine all of the possible isomorphisms and also the $\varphi(b)=c$ part does that just mean redraw the graph interchanging b and c?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You need to find all maps (in fact permutations) $f\colon V\to V$ such that $f(b)=c$ and whenever $xy$ is an edge then also $f(x)f(y)$ is an edge.

You can argue as follows: $a$ is a neighbour of $b$ and has degree $2$, hence $f(a)$ must be a neighbour of $f(b)=c$ and must also have degree $2$. This implies $f(a)=d$. Similarly $f(d)=a$ and thus par force $f(e)=e$. We conclude that there is only one such isomorphism.

Comment: ok so I check all the possible isomorphic graphs when c and b are interchanged?

Comment: yes, but the number of possible isomorphic graphs with $b$ and $c$ interchanged is considerably reduced because an isomorphism $f$ maps each vertex to another vertex of the same degree.  Thus, $f$ must fix $e$ since it is the unique vertex of degree 4.  For the same reason, $f$ must permute the elements of $\{b,c\}$ (i.e. it $f$ fixes $\{b,c\}$ setwise), and it fixed $\{a,d\}$ setwise.  Finally, if $f$ maps $b$ to $c$, it must map the neighbors of $b$ (such as $a$) to the neighbors of $c$ (such as $d$).  Thus, if $f$ interchanges $b$ and $c$, it also interchanges $a$ and $d$.